# X-Fi XtremeGamer under Windows 10

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-10, sound-card

So, I have a Soundblaster X-Fi XtremeGamer, and I've installed Windows 10 on my machine. Everything seems to work ok, except that I have no sound. I noticed on the Creative website that they expect to have a driver out for the Creative X-Fi XtremeGamer for Windows 10 sometime in September 2015 (roughly a month away).

In the meantime, is there anything I can do you get sound? I was able to install some non-Creative drivers, but I only get the option for SPDIF out (which my card doesn't have anyway) and I can't connect my speakers (normal audio cable) to get sound (in other words, if I connect my speakers, I still receive no sound).  Windows reports that it cannot play any test tones. :(

I do have an ASUS M2N32-SLI motherboard, which has onboard sound, but that doesn't seem to work at the moment, either. Windows 10 doesn't even seem to recognize that audio device.

I'd like to play some games between now and September, so does anyone know if it's possible for me to get *some* audio in the meantime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look if your onboard audio interface is disabled in the BIOS. If so, you could enable it and use in in the meantime until there are drivers for you card on win 10.

Have you tried to install the drivers for Win 8.1 for your card? I think so, just for sake of completion.

Another way could be to remove your xfi and then see if Win10 detects the onboard sound then.

Comment: Yep, my onboard card was disabled in the bios. It's been so long since I've used it, I forgot that I had done this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed this:

1. Load the Creative SBXF_PCDRV_L11_2_30_0007 Windows 10 driver.
2. Open Creative Audio control panel.
3. Under headphone detection, uncheck **Automatically Mute Speakers**.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.creative.com/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?catID=1&subCatID=208&prodID=17791&prodName=Sound%20Blaster%20X-Fi%20Titanium%20Fatal1ty%20Professional%20Series&subCatName=X-Fi%20Series&CatName=Sound+Blaster&VARSET=prodfaq:PRODFAQ_17791,VARSET=CategoryID:1

windows 10 pack for xfi cards it solved all the crackling and freezing/loading issues

Comment: What, specifically, is your solution and how does this post relate to the question?